# How to retrieve only Values of the object ( AdminDirectory.Users.list)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using "AdminDirectory.Users.list" to export the users it's working fine however i want to filter the "user.organizations" value currently i am getting output "{customType=, costCenter=Mortgage Loans, description=, title=, department=Sales, primary=true}" how can i make sure that i will get output of costCenter only (Mortgage Loans)

[image]

```js
  "organizations": [
    {
      "name": string,
      "title": string,
      "primary": boolean,
      "type": string,
      "customType": string,
      "department": string,
      "symbol": string,
      "location": string,
      "description": string,
      "domain": string,
      "costCenter": string,
      "fullTimeEquivalent": integer
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard property in Google API called '`fields`' where you can specify which value you want returned instead of the whole file resources (*). And Admin [Users.list Try-it](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#try-it) also has it.

I'm going to use the [Drive API list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) as I don't work with Admin SDK but the concept should translate easily.

```
{
  "files": [
    {
       "owners": [
          {
           "kind": "drive#user",
           "displayName": "noogui",
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I wanted to ask for all the '`files`' property, I'd pass something like `fields = files` in the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it). If I wanted to get all the `owners` children inside '`files`', I'd pass something like

`fields = files(owners)`.

If I wanted to get the `displayName` only, I'd pass something like

`fields = files(owners(displayName))`.

The implementation may vary per language, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still needed help with this. But I think what you needed is to get the costCenter value. You use it like this in Google Apps Script for a get example, you can just modify that to match your list request.

```
var userInfo = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user, {fields: 'organizations', viewType:'domain_public'});

var userCostCenter = userInfo.organizations[0].costCenter;
if(userCostCenter  == "Mortgage Loans"){
...
}
```

You can also use the q parameter to limit the results. You can check the [syntax on this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

Comment: Thanks, 

How to use projection: "custom" to pull orgCostCenter and externalId of all users .

function listUsers() {

 var userList = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    customer: 'my_customer',
    maxResults: 100,
    viewType: 'domain_public',
   projection: "custom"{orgCostCenter=, :}
  }).users;

Logger.log(userList)
}

Comment: You can use the custom projection for custom schema. For example for:

 "customSchemas": {
  "SchemaSample": {
   "TestField": "TestValue"
  }

You can access it like this:
var userList = AdminDirectory.Users.list({customer: 'my_customer', maxResults: 10, viewType:'domain_public', customFieldMask:'SchemaSample', projection:'custom'}).users;

I suggest check first with projection full if orgCostCenter exists as customSchema.